# SqlConnection Doesn't Honor Timeout for IP Address Data Sources (.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, connection-timeout

In my application I have set the Connection Timeout attribute on a connection string to 10 seconds. I have verified this by checking the ConnectionTimeout property on the SqlConnection object right before Open is called. However, when I attempt to open a connection to a server that is unreachable, it takes about a minute before an exception is thrown, and not 10 seconds.

The specific error is:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.SqlClient.dll but was not handled in user code: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

In my situation the target server is simply turned off. SQL Server Management Studio similarly takes about a minute for the connection to fail when using it to attempt to connect to the same server.

UPDATE

I created a C# console app to test, and set the timeout value to 3 seconds. If I use an IP address I get timeouts around 47 seconds no matter how low the connection timeout is. If I use an arbitrary string then I get timeouts that roughly equivalent to the timeout I specify. So this issue has something to do with using IPV4 addresses instead of domain names. Here is the test app:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Hi Mom, I'm on the internet!");

      string conn_str = 
      "Data Source=<Some Address>;" + 
      "Initial Catalog=BLAHBLA;" + 
      "User ID=HOOTENANY;" + 
      "Password=password;" + 
      "Connect Timeout=3";

      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str)) {
        Console.WriteLine(conn.ConnectionTimeout);
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try {
          conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine("Time till error: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString() + " seconds.");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know you say you are sure about this, but many apps really depend on this. Can you please share a simple code example that demonstrates this behaviour, I am not able to reproduce your issue with SqlConnection directly, but I have seen this can occur in misconfigured EF implementations.

Comment: And add the output of nslookup for the host name.  Need to see if there are multiple IPs.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Not multiple IPs since the issue has to do with using an IP directly.

Comment: Wow! @DavidBrowne-Microsoft If I use an IP4 address as the datasource I can reproduce the issue exactly! Except with a timeout of 5s or more are always 21 seconds

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I want to share the code that I used to Prove this issue identified by Ian.

- I have verified this behaviour in v2.0, 2.1 and 2.2.301

> I don't want to edit OPs post because it is good enough, but I do want to facilitate more experiments in this area so we can get this issue sorted out :)

The following code demonstrates that the first attempt to connect to an IP address that resolves to a host will fail pretty reliably at 47 seconds, however immediate retrys on the same IP consistently fail at 21 seconds.

It is interesting that there is a consistent initial failure time of 52 seconds for an IP on my subnet that does not resolve to a host, before dropping back to 21 seconds.

- My interpretation of this is that part of the delay is due to resolution (~26 seconds for a host that exists, ~31s for an IP on the same subnet that does not resolve.), and that once the the IP resolution to a host is available from cache we still experience 21 seconds of delay somewhere else in the chain.

Test code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] timeouts = new int[] { 5, 1, 10, 20, 30 };
            string[] ips = new string[] {
                "DoesNotExist", // Host that does not resolve to an IP address on my network
                "192.168.0.1", // IP address that exists, only one host on the network, it is NOT running a sql service
                "311.1.15.82", // fictitious IP that does not resolve a host, should have same results as a name that doesn't resolve
                "192.168.0.181", // IP address that is on my subnet, but again does not resolve to a host at all.
            };
            foreach (var ip in ips)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Data Source: {ip}");
                foreach (var timeout in timeouts)
                {
                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection($"Data Source={ip};Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={timeout}"))
                    {
                        Console.Write($"Timeout: {conn.ConnectionTimeout}s");
                        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            timer.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine($" - Connected in: {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            timer.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine($" - Failed in: {timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: *compiled against .Net Core v2.2.301*

```
Data Source: DoesNotExist
Timeout: 5s - Failed in: 7.1730095s
Timeout: 1s - Failed in: 2.2943659s
Timeout: 10s - Failed in: 9.754597s
Timeout: 20s - Failed in: 19.3288328s
Timeout: 30s - Failed in: 29.1020866s

Data Source: 192.168.0.1
Timeout: 5s - Failed in: 47.5502805s
Timeout: 1s - Failed in: 21.0405047s
Timeout: 10s - Failed in: 21.0482195s
Timeout: 20s - Failed in: 21.0320983s
Timeout: 30s - Failed in: 42.1433989s

Data Source: 311.1.15.82
Timeout: 5s - Failed in: 4.5533743s
Timeout: 1s - Failed in: 0.7421621s
Timeout: 10s - Failed in: 9.5509966s
Timeout: 20s - Failed in: 19.5665214s
Timeout: 30s - Failed in: 29.5764756s

Data Source: 192.168.0.181
Timeout: 5s - Failed in: 52.0493217s
Timeout: 1s - Failed in: 21.0335449s
Timeout: 10s - Failed in: 21.0365022s
Timeout: 20s - Failed in: 21.0402679s
Timeout: 30s - Failed in: 42.1391708s
```

I hope this observation helps find the real solution, note that the number obtained from running this code compiled against other earlier releases of .Net core v2 are very similar.

Comment: I hit this today when testing appSettings.json connection strings in NUnit. As far as I can tell the bowels of `SqlConnection` is using `TcpClient.BeginConnect()` internally and this seems to be causing an 11 second delay for me when connecting to IP addresses that don't exist on the network (or aren't listening on the configured port). When I avoided `SqlConnection` and used `var connected = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(hostname, port).Wait(millisecondsTimeout);` things connected or timed out as expected. I'm thinking it's a .NET Core bug in `TcpClient.BeginConnect()`.

Comment: I'm seeing a related issue with the data source "I" (from a bad config). It just hangs forever, even though there's a connection timeout of 5 seconds. So it seems this isn't the only case where the connection timeout is being disregarded...